# If $f: \mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}^q$ is continuous then $\overline{f(A)} = f(\overline{A})$ for bounded $A\subset \mathbb{R}^p$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I would like a verification of a proof of the following statement. Let $f : \mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}^q$ be a continuous function. Show that if $A$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^p$, then $\overline{f(A)} = f(\overline{A})$.

Let $x \in \overline{A}$. Then there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $A$ converging to $x$. Since $f$ is continuous, the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ converges to $f(x)$. Therefore $f(x) \in \overline{f(A)}$, so $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$.

Now let $y \in \overline{f(A)}$. Then there exists a sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ in $f(A)$ converging to $y$. Now $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $A$. Since $A$ is bounded, $\{x_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence $\{x_n'\}$ with limit $x \in \overline{A}$. Then $\{f(x_n')\}$ is a subsequence of $\{f(x_n)\}$. Therefore $\{f(x_n')\}$ converges to $y$. Since $f$ is continuous, we must have $f(x) = y$. Therefore $y \in f(\overline{A})$, so $\overline{f(A)} \subset f(\overline{A})$.

I would also be interested in alternative proofs, particularly ones that don't use sequences. Thanks!

Comment: may you seek for theorem of  Heine Borel, weak version ??!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another proof :

$\overline{A}$ is closed and bounded in $\Bbb R^n$, so it's a compact. It follow that $f( \overline{A} )$ is compact, so it's closed.

But as $f(A) \subset f(\overline{A})$, we have $\overline{f(A)} \subset f(\overline{A})$ because $\overline{f(A)}$ is the smallest closed set that contain $f(A)$.

Now, $B = f^{-1}( \overline{f(A)} )$ is a closed set that contain $A$, so it contain $\overline{A}$, hence $f(\overline{A}) \subset f(B) = \overline{f(A)}$